# AutoComplete на Django

Tags: python, django

Необходимо реализовать что-то вроде [AutoComplete](http://djangonaut.blogspot.com/2008/05/jquery-autocompletewidget-django.html), но с заполнением одного поля, а остальные нужные поля дополнились данными автоматически. Я как понял, по ссылке это для `django-admin` сделано или ошибаюсь? В общем, желательно боевой код глянуть такой реализации, если возможно...

Answer (score 2):

Нет, по ссылке приведен код виджета, который может быть использован для поля в любой форме (в том числе и в админке). Для его использования нужно только передать его в параметре widget для нужных полей в форме, написать представление, возвращающее нужные данные из базы и добавить его в urls.py.